# Android Action Down with radio button

Tags: java, android, button, radio-button, audiotrack

I'm currently trying to make my project so that when one of the radio buttons are selected and a button is held then it produces the selected sound. however when I used the ACTION_DOWN function, no noise is produced. Any help would be great

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int frequency = Integer.parseInt(frequencyInput.getText().toString());
    displayFrequency.setText(String.valueOf(frequency));
    sineWave.setSine(frequency);
    squareWave.setSquareWave(frequency);
    sawWave.setSawWave(frequency);
    boolean on = ((startStop.isPressed()) && sine.isChecked());
    boolean sqOn = ((startStop.isPressed()) && square.isChecked());
    boolean sawOn =((startStop.isPressed()) && saw.isChecked());
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (on)
            {
                sineWave.start();
            }
            else if (sqOn)
                {
                 squareWave.start();
                }

            else if (sawOn)
                  {
                sawWave.start();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!on) {
                sineWave.stop();
            }
            if (!sqOn) {
                squareWave.stop();
            }
            if (!sawOn) {
                sawWave.stop();
                ;
            }
            break;


            }
```

Comment: my guess is, that at the moment when `onTouch` is getting called, `startStop.isPressed()` is `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you check for `isPressed()` while you are still in `onTouch`, so the pressed state of the button has not been set yet.

If you add the `onTouchListener` directly to the startStop button you can be sure that every time it is called it is the startStop button that triggered the event. This allows you to remove the `startStop.isPressed()` check.

```
  startStop.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int frequency = Integer.parseInt(frequencyInput.getText().toString());
            displayFrequency.setText(String.valueOf(frequency));
            sineWave.setSine(frequency);
            squareWave.setSquareWave(frequency);
            sawWave.setSawWave(frequency);
            boolean on = sine.isChecked();
            boolean sqOn = square.isChecked();
            boolean sawOn = saw.isChecked();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (on) {
                        sineWave.start();
                    } else if (sqOn) {
                        squareWave.start();
                    } else if (sawOn) {
                        sawWave.start();
                    }
                    break;    
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!on) {
                        sineWave.stop();
                    }
                    if (!sqOn) {
                        squareWave.stop();
                    }
                    if (!sawOn) {
                        sawWave.stop();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still doesn't quite work as its the main activity and implements onTouchListener, it needs to remain abstract.

Comment: That was basically the main point my suggestion: don't implement the OnTouchListener globally in the activity but do it directly for the button.

Comment: If you really really want to implement the listener into the activity you can set a tag to the button in the xml and check that in the beginning of onTouch callback.