# RadioGroup setOnCheckedChangeListener not work with RadioButton setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android

I have a RadioGroup with RadioButtons inside. My problem was when i check radiobutton listener will not work. When I delete radiobutton touchlistener event it will works.

```
final RadioGroup RGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.RGroup);

    RGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
            if (isChecked)
            {
                checkedRadioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp);
            }
        }
    });
```

This code works when i remove below code

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int colorFrom = v.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent);
                    int colorTo = v.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAnswer);
                    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
                    colorAnimation.setDuration(1000); // milliseconds
                    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                            button.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                        }

                    });
                    colorAnimation.start();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Layout of radiobuttons

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/slide_question"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_7dp"
    android:id="@+id/RGroup">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pad_5dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pad_5dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/pad_7dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Maybe listeners conflicts

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531910/android-action-down-with-radio-button/42532694#42532694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It is because the listener conflictions. When you are applying touchListener at that time it's stopping the checkChangeListener of the group to get the event.

Still try out `return false` from the onTouch method check if it's working or not. 
Post the behaviour after trying.